# SQL where statement, can it use a wild card for the column name?

Tags: html, sql, jsp, jdbc

I have a query:

> ```
>     <sql:query var="result" dataSource="jdbc/XXXX">
>         Select top 1000 max(IP),max(mail0),etc,etc,etc,etc,etc from PCOwners
>
>         inner join user on PCOwners.ID = user.Name0
>         inner join wol on PCOwners.namename = mach
>
>         where Name0 = ? <sql:param value="blahblahblah" />
>
>         group by Name0
>         order by Name0 desc
>     </sql:query>
> ```

and, I want the

> where Name0 = ? sql:param value="blahblahblah" />

to be something like

> where '%' = ? sql:param value="blahblahblah" />

because, I want the:

```
     ? <sql:param value="blahblahblah" />
```

to accept anything the user inputs (i know, i know....)....

becuase, i want the user to get results if they enter part/all of anything contained within any column

can/how do I do something inplace of

> column

that will mean

> any column

??????

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that. A prepared statement consists in passing a parameterized statement to the database so that it prepares the execution plan of the query, in order to execute it later. To be able to prepare the execution plan, the database needs to know the column names, because the plan depends on them (for example, selecting by name would use the index on the name, but selecting by age would not).

Comment: hmmm...bc, I have a text box (with a submit button) and, on the other side, the query has    where this = that or where these = those or where thine = ummmYours

Comment: However, I wanted to NOT list all of them...bc, the user could enter a dozen differnt valid inputs (firt name, last name, full name, email, employee number....) I wanted that variable to be run against any/all column, and, if its a hit - HE SHOOTS, HE sCORES!!! ....but, no, huh???

Comment: You can do that, but by creating the SQL query dynamically, using simple string concatenation or printf(). Not by using a prepared statement with the column name as a parameter.